# Android is there a way to make a widget available in every tab (TabHost)?

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs, android-widget

I need to make a ViewFlipper available in every tab of the TabHost. Then it comes down, it should cover everything, including the tabs. I tried instantiating in the TabHost and TabWidget, but it gave me NullPointer every time I tried to make an attribution using the findViewById. Any ideas?

Using API 8

Comment: You search ways to implement [swiping between tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134332)?

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. For example, say I have 3 tabs. When a certain condition applies, a SlidingDrawer (In my case a ViewFlipper with an animation from top to bottom) will come in and cover everything, the 3 tabs and the contents. How do I manage to do this? I though I could just implement a ViewFlipper in the layout, but it seems that It is not possible with TabActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was put the widget in the main tab activity (TabActivity). Then, I created a method such as:

```
public ViewFlipper getWidget(){
   return this.mWidget;
}
```

Then I was able to call it from any child activity.

I strongly recommend anyone reading this to follow the docs and other users advice: do not use TabActivity. There are other solutions that are better than TabActivity.