# Swipe menu like in Navigation android app

Tags: android, menu, tabs, swipe

I'd like to have a similar swipe menu like in Navigation app. When the current item is moved to the edge (second picture, "shortcuts" is moved to right edge), it hits the neighbouring item (contacts):

[image] [image] [image]

I've found only [SwipeyTabs](http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html), but that's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Android-ViewPagerIndicator

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

try the sample application

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you want to create an [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) with Tabs and View Pager for Swipe Navigation? You may check this out: [How do I implement swiping between tabs on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134332/how-do-i-implement-swiping-between-tabs-on-android/10134336#10134336)

If you want Tabs + Swipe also for lower Android versions you could also try [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think u can do this by also selecting Navigation Type -> Scrollable Tabs + Swipe ,while creating new project and for Activity type,It gives the same swipe screen but with only letters 1 2 3 for each pages,,try to send your custom view for these Fragments showing 1 2 3 and its done like you wanted.
PS: I am not sure about the efficiency of this method though