# Fragment Not Selected Crash

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, crash

I have a problem ... I would like to select a tab using actionbar not yet created, how could I do to create it as well as click on it? I could instantiate it and then what? I can not quite understand I've made several attempts: (
Thank you in advance :)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.megadown.megacodownloader.Tab_Search$2.onClick(Tab_Search.java:215)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question, but if you want to create a `TabBar` in your `ActionBar` (please read [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) to get the right library) than you have to add the following code into your `Activity`:

```
    // i use ActionBarSherlock library:
    // get an instance of your actionbar and set your navigation mode to tabbar
    mContext.getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    //create a tab and add it to your actionbar
    tabHome = mContext.getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    tabHome.setText(tabItemHome);
    tabHome.setTag(tabItemHome);
    tabHome.setTabListener(this); // TabListener
    mContext.getSupportActionBar().addTab(tabHome);
```

To check which tab was clicked you have to implement an `TabListener` (in my code example the activity implements a tablistener). Than you can override the following methods:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // todo
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // todo
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // todo
}
```

If you have more questions, let me know.

Comment: I think I have explained myself badly.
In my app I want to select the 3 tab, only when I want to say or select to appear, it has not yet been created or instaziata.
To create it I should go on it so I can click on it and then do various tasks.
I wanted to know how to create it without clicking on it and then select it.

Comment: 'code'                                 MainActivity.actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);

Comment: Yes, i think i solved it, but can i know how to put swipe in action bar? Minium api 13

Comment: If the answer helped you to solve your question than you should also mark it! If you want swipe than you should use `viewPager`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134332/how-do-i-implement-swiping-between-tabs-on-android.

Comment: I saw this post, but i didn't do it :( because my app crash

Comment: I think you should mark my answer and open a new question with the problems you get by initializing your swipe Fragment. It's the best you put into your question what you already did and where your problem is. Try to be so clear as possible. Thanks.