# How to implement the swipe view in android project?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, android-tablelayout

I am new to android.I tried many ways but I cannot able to understood how to implement a swipe view in my android project.

I have a **six** tabs:

> 1.Home
>
> 2.Video
>
> 3.Audio
>
> 4.Gallery
>
> 5.Blog
>
> 6.More

I referred android docs about swipe view.I cannot able to understood how to implement the swipe view in android project.anybody can help me with these.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here lots of url to make this view you can follow any one:

http://just-another-blog.net/programming/how-to-implement-horizontal-view-swiping-with-tabs/

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#swipe-tabs

[How do I implement swiping between tabs on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134332/how-do-i-implement-swiping-between-tabs-on-android)

I hope it will work for you.