# ActionBar: Swipe between Tabs with ViewPager

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I tried to make swiping between my tabs possible in my app. To do this i followed this
answer: 
[How do I implement swiping between tabs on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134332/how-do-i-implement-swiping-between-tabs-on-android)

Now that I´ve inserted this code, I get lots of errors.

This is my code:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 final ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();

            mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
           mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener{
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position){
                getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

          tabA = mActionBar.newTab();
          tabA.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
          tabA.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_a);
            tabA.setTabListener(new ActionBar.TabListener(){
                public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                          FragmentTransaction ft){

                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }

            });
            mActionBar.addTab(tabA);

}}
```

Errors:

```
tabA.setTabListener(new ActionBar.TabListener(){
                public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                          FragmentTransaction ft){

                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                }

            });
```

Class 'Anonymous derived from TabListener' must either be declared abstract or declare abstract method 'OnTabUnselected(Tab,FragmentTransaction)' in 'TabListener'.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener{

            public void onPageSelected(int position){
                getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
```

Error at the "{" after SimpleOnPageChangeListener:
'(' or '[' expected
')' expected
';' expected

and another Error at the end: ')' 'Unexpected Token'

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) is part of the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html). You need to add the `android-support-v4.jar` file (found in `<sdk>\extras\android\support\v4` as a library for your project.

See the [Setup guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) for instructions.

**EDIT** As to the new errors:

- "()" are missing in new `ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){`
- TabListeners must implement a few more methods. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html

Comment: Okay, that worked,thanks! But i am still getting errors, i will post the code in the original post.